# Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type '() => Map<String, dynamic> '

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a data table for filtering with buttons. I have watched a tutorial.

I have to create an object (named: `Kasalar_object`). I have called the `StreamBuilder` widget in my column. And I created my `DataSourceTable`.

After that, I replaced my source with my `DataSourceTable`, but I have to put my values to my object.  And I tried to put it, but my app shows:

> Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type '() => Map<String, dynamic> '

There is no error at streaming. Because when I tried to use it without object. It works. Here is my code:

My object:

```
class Kasalar_object  {
 final String kasa_adi;
 final String doviz_cinsi;
 final String acilis_bakiyesi;
 final String olusturulma_tarihi;
 final  String aktivite;

 Kasalar_object( {required this.kasa_adi , required this.doviz_cinsi, required this.acilis_bakiyesi, required this.olusturulma_tarihi, required this.aktivite});

//     Map<String, dynamic>
  factory Kasalar_object.fromMap( Map<String, dynamic> kasalar_objectim )  {
    return Kasalar_object(
      kasa_adi: kasalar_objectim['kasa_adi'],
      doviz_cinsi: kasalar_objectim['doviz_cinsi'],
      acilis_bakiyesi: kasalar_objectim['acilis_bakiyesi'],
    olusturulma_tarihi: kasalar_objectim['olusturulma_tarihi'],
    aktivite:  kasalar_objectim['aktivite'], ); // );   
  }

  StreamBuilder(
     stream:  firestore.collection("Users").doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email).collection("kasalar").snapshots(),
     builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snap) {
          List<Kasalar_object> kasalarim = [];

          kasalarim = snap.data!.docs.map((e) => Kasalar_object.fromMap(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic> )).toList();

            final DataTableSource _all_kasa = MyKasaData(kasalarim);

            List<dynamic> map = snap.data!.docs;

        if(snap.hasData ){
              return PaginatedDataTable(
                columns:  [        
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Kasa Adi'),),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Para Birimi')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Açılıs Bakiyesi')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Oluşturulma Tarihi')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Aktif/Pasif')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('İslemler')),
                ],
                source: _all_kasa,
                columnSpacing: witdh/15,
              );
        }
        else{
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()); // new Text('No data...');
        }
      }),
```

Also my dataSourceTable:

```
class MyKasaData extends DataTableSource {    

  SideBarController sideBarController = Get.put(SideBarController());    

  // List<Kasalar> kasalar = [];

  MyKasaData(this._data);

  final List<dynamic> _data;

  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['kasa_adi'])),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['doviz_cinsi'])),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['acilis_bakiyesi'])),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['olusturulma_tarihi'])),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['aktivite'])), }
```

And Here is error message's image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwnto.png)

if I change the data to data() here is the result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOGh3.png)

How can I fix it?

Comment: `list.data` -> `list.data()`

Comment: NosuchMethodError: 'data'. Dynamic call of null. Receiver: Instance of 'Kasalar_object'. Arguments:[] . Now, I get it this error message.

Comment: Please post your updated code with the modification.

Comment: I did it your words.

Comment: Inside your `MyKasaData` class, change `final List<dynamic> _data;` to `final List<Kasalar_object> _data;`. Now change your `_data[index].data()['kasa_adi']` calls to `_data[index].kasa_adi` respectively. See if that works now.

Comment: ok. It works. But Can you expain it. Why I should use data() method and why I should cange to _data[index].kasa_adi ? Also, You should give the answer to my question for getting reputation point.

Comment: Sure, I can add an answer!

Comment: thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code had the following line (formatted for better readability):

```dart
kasalarim = snap.data!
    .docs
    .map((e) => Kasalar_object.fromMap(e.data as Map<String, dynamic>))
    .toList();
```

Here, `snap` is a `AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>`, and `snap.data!` is therefore a `QuerySnapshot`.

Every `QuerySnapshot` has a [`docs` *property*](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docs.html), which returns a `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>`.

Every `QueryDocumentSnapshot` has a [`data` *method*](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot/data.html), which returns a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

The difference between a *property* and a *method* in Dart is that the former you can call without parenthesis after its symbol, while the method you must use parenthesis. Therefore, changing `e.data` to `e.data()` would effectively invoke the method and solve the error "Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type '() => Map<String, dynamic>'".

---

Your updated code then had the following code (also formatted for better readability):

```dart
class MyKasaData extends DataTableSource {
  SideBarController sideBarController = Get.put(SideBarController());

  final List<dynamic> _data;

  MyKasaData(this._data);

  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['kasa_adi'])),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['doviz_cinsi'])),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['acilis_bakiyesi'])),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['olusturulma_tarihi'])),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['aktivite']))
    ]);
  }
}
```

where you created an instance passing `kasalarim` to its constructor:

```
List<Kasalar_object> kasalarim = snap.data!
    .docs
    .map((e) => Kasalar_object.fromMap(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic> ))
    .toList();

final DataTableSource _all_kasa = MyKasaData(kasalarim);
```

Note that `kasalarim` is a list of `Kasalar_object`, which have only the attributes `kasa_adi`, `doviz_cinsi`, `acilis_bakiyesi`, `olusturulma_tarihi` and `aktivite`.

Passing `kasalarim` to `MyKasaData` would make its `_data` field contain a list of `Kasalar_object`. So, calling

```dart
_data[index].data()['kasa_adi']
```

would try to call a method named `data()` on a `Kasalar_object`, which does not exist! What a `Kasalar_object` does have is a `kasa_adi` attribute, which you can access directly:

```dart
class MyKasaData extends DataTableSource {
  SideBarController sideBarController = Get.put(SideBarController());

  final List<dynamic> _data;

  MyKasaData(this._data);

  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].kasa_adi)),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].doviz_cinsi)),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].acilis_bakiyesi)),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].olusturulma_tarihi)),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].aktivite))
    ]);
  }
}
```

Finally, [using `dynamic` is bad](https://dart.dev/effective-dart/design#avoid-using-dynamic-unless-you-want-to-disable-static-checking), so make `_data` a `List<Kasalar_object>`, which you help you to detect this error beforehand.